# How can I get ggtree::geom_range to work?

Tags: r, ggtree

I am trying to add range bars to nodes as described in the [treedata book](http://yulab-smu.top/treedata-book/chapter5.html#uncertainty-of-evolutionary-inference). Here is an example from the book of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: trees with bars]

Note the red bars.

Here is code that should create a tree image with red bars:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(treeio)
library(ggtree)

# create a tree and add a numeric annotation called 'range'
tree = rtree(3) %>% as.treedata %>% as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(range=0.1) %>% 
  as.treedata

# plot the tree and add red bars with geom_bar()
ggtree(tree)  + geom_range(range='range', color="red")
```

[image: tree without bars]

However, the resulting plot does not have red bars.

What do I need to do in order to add red bars to every node?

I am using ggtree v2.2.4, treeio v1.12.0, and ggplot2 v3.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only giving a single value to `range`. In the example you linked, the column `range` is a list, where each row contains a minimum and maximum value. So you probably want something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(treeio)
library(ggtree)

# create a tree and add a numeric annotation called 'range'
tree = rtree(3) %>% as.treedata %>% as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(number = 1:5,
        range = lapply(number, function(x) c(-0.1, 0.1) + x)) %>% 
  as.treedata

# plot the tree and add red bars with geom_bar()
ggtree(tree)  + 
  geom_range("number", range='range', color="red", size = 3, alpha = 0.3) + 
  theme_tree2()
```

[image]